# How to reduce the absolute file path in java

Tags: java, file

There is an automated report in which the path is decided by

```
File file = new File(FileOperations.getInstance().getAbsolutePath(ConfigReader.getInstance().getChartPath())+"/"+this.fileName);
```

But because of this, the image is giving 404 as it is setting path as

> /home/User/locustapitest/target/cucumber-reports/locustcharts/performanceChart1594459662333.png

and I need only

> /locustapitest/target/cucumber-reports/locustcharts/performanceChart1594459662333.png

Is there any way to remove /home/User from the absolute path?

Answer (score 3):

The absolute path is what it is.  If you remove `"/home/User"` then it won't be the correct absolute path.

However, you can easily remove a prefix from the start of a string.  For example

```
   String full = "/home/User/locustapitest/target/foo.png"
   String prefix = "/home/User";
   if (full.startsWith(prefix)) {
       String shortened = full.substring(prefix.length(), full.length());
       // or            = full.substring(prefix.length());
   }
```

Check the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) for `String.substring(int, int)` to understand what this is doing.